# what's wrong with this python code

Tags: python

This is a code with Web crawler.
I'm a beginer in learning python.So i don't know how to solve.
It seems wrong with search()

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
import urllib,urllib2,re
class BDTB:
    def __init__(self,baseUrl,seeLZ):
        self.baseUrl = baseUrl
        self.seeLZ = '?see_lz' + str(seeLZ)
    def getPage(self,pageNum):
        try:
            url = self.baseUrl + self.seeLZ + '&pn=' + str(pageNum)
            request = urllib2.Request(url)
            response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
            #print response.read().decode('utf-8')
            return response
        except urllib2.URLError,e:
            if hasattr(e,'reason'):
                print u'连接百度贴吧失败，错误原因',e.reason
                return None
    def getTitle(self):
        page = self.getPage(1)
        pattern = re.compile('<h3 class.*?px">(.*?)</h3>',re.S)
        result = re.search(pattern,page)
        if result:
            print result.group(1)
            return result.group(1).strip()
        else:
            return None
baseURL = 'http://tieba.baidu.com/p/4095047339'
bdtb = BDTB(baseURL,1)
bdtb.getTitle()
```

Comment: It will be very helpful to post error  :)

Comment: Why are you trying to parse HTML with regex? Learn more about [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

Comment: or use pyquery.  not as comprehensive as BeautifulSoup, but jquery selector use means you can test in browser first.  Still, no reason to downvote a reasonable question by a noob who did work on it first.  +1 folks, chill on -1s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will raise a `TypeError: expected string or buffer` because you are passing the object returned from `urllib2.urlopen(request)` to `re.search()` when it requires an `str`.

If you change the return value from:

```
return responce  # returns the object
```

to one that returns the text contained in the request:

```
return responce.read()  # returns the text contained in the responce
```

Your script works and after executing it returns:

```
广告兼职及二手物品交易集中贴
```

*Additionally*, since you're working with `Python 2.x` you might want to change you object from `class BDTB:` to `class BDTB(object)` in order to use [**new style classes**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54867/what-is-the-difference-between-old-style-and-new-style-classes-in-python).

Comment: because of coding,so I modify it as  response.read().decode('utf-8')